# Openni_camera starts ok, but no image/data

Tags: openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just install ROS-Diamondback and Openni_kinect. I've did everything told on wikis. I've install this both manual and with package, but everytime I don't receive any data from sensor. If I do roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch, this happen...

> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid
> [2247]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> setting /run_id to
> e639cd8c-b3a9-11e0-8766-4c0f6ed792e5
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid
> [2260] started core service [/rosout]
> process[openni_node1-2]: started with
> pid [2263]
> process[kinect_base_link-3]: started
> with pid [2264]
> process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started
> with pid [2265]
> process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started
> with pid [2266]
> process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started
> with pid [2267] [ INFO]
> [1311260319.304629415]:
> [/openni_node1] Number devices
> connected: 1 [ INFO]
> [1311260319.305017698]:
> [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus
> 003:06 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from
> Microsoft (45e) with serial id
> 'A00364A13327050A' [ INFO]
> [1311260319.308811029]:
> [/openni_node1] searching for device
> with index = 1 [ INFO]
> [1311260319.359187371]:
> [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI
> Camera' on bus 3:6 with serial number
> 'A00364A13327050A' [ INFO]
> [1311260319.382045241]: rgb_frame_id =
> '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' [ INFO]
> [1311260319.385222797]: depth_frame_id
> = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'

Everything seems to work fine but when I do rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_color, no data is streamed. Though if I run libfreenect or windows API, Kinect works perfectly...

Any idea how to solve this?

Simon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10681/openni_camera-starts-ok,-but-no-image/data./) by [HoTiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/869/hotix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-07-21**:
Same problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it working but I had an eSata port on my laptop.

[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/1626/kinect-and-usb-30) it explains!

---

Originally posted by [HoTiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/869/hotix/) with karma: 26 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0